# Ultraweak topology on Banach spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces with $Y$ reflexive, then the space $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ of bounded operators from $X$ to $Y$ is the dual of the projective tensor product of $X$ and $Y^{*}$. As in the case where $X=Y=\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space, this induces a weak*-topology on $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$, which in the Hilbert space setting is called the ultraweak topology. In the Hilbert space setting, the finite rank operators lie dense in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ with respect to this topology. Does the same statement hold for $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$? If not in general, what if we assume that $Y$ has an (unconditional) Schauder basis? Does anyone know whether this topology on $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ has been studied in the Banach space setting?

Comment: Jan, you should not ask simultanepusly on MO and here. People do not like it...